# from Inline-JavaScript to addEventListener

Tags: click, addeventlistener

what i've to change to run? here is my current code (foto upload function):

```
[submit attributes='onclick="return psValidateForm() && Redirect();"']
```

code for [submit] :

```
        case "[submit]":
            if($atts && is_array($atts) && array_key_exists('name', $atts)){
                $submitname = $atts['name'];
            } else {
                $submitname = 'bwbps_submitBtn';
            }
            $ret = '<input type="submit" class="ps-submit" value="'.$submitname.'" id="' . $g["pfx"] . 'bwbps_submitBtn" name="bwbps_submitBtn" ' . $fld_attributes . '/>';
            break;
```

the action: a user wants to upload a foto -> function psValidateForm check if all required inputs have value -> when its ok the foto will upload -> redirect to another page

this is my redirect function:

```
function Redirect() 
   { window.setTimeout('window.location="https://url/"', 5000);
}
```

problem: if the internet connection slow, or the image size very high -> 5s is not enough time to upload the image.

solution:

```
bwbps_submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (psValidateForm()) {
    Redirect();
  } else {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

html now just:

```
[submit]
```

error in firebug:

```
TypeError: Value not an object.
error source line:


bwbps_submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {


ReferenceError: bwbps_submitBtn is not defined
error source line:


bwbps_submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```

whats wrong? can anoybody help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError: bwbps_submitBtn is not defined!!! Get this object 'bwbps_submitBtn' with document.getElementById or similar to the variable 'bwbps_submitBtn'.